# How to replace characters at the beginning and at the end of a word?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
var string = This is a *piece* of text.
```

I could do:

```
string.replace(/\*/g, <em>)
```

However, I would get this: `<em>piece<em>`. And what I want to get is this: `<em>piece</em>`.

How to modify this code so I can detect the `*` character at the beginning and end of a word?

Comment: I guess you are trying to convert a string to markdown by your self. This is a kind of re-inventing the wheel and a bad practice as you DRY. I guess you could use libraries like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown

Comment: @MerianosNikos There are too many customizations I want to make. For example adding `.no-indent` and `.scene-break` classes, as well as converting --- and ^^. So I think writing my own is faster.

Comment: Does `**text**` convert to `<strong>text</strong>`? Does `_text_` convert to `<em>text</em>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use capturing groups like this:

```js
var string = 'This is a *piece* of text.'

var r = string.replace(/\*([^\*]+)\*/, (m, m1) =>
  `<em>${m1}</em>`)

console.log(r)
```

Even better you could build regex on the fly with any boundry character

```js
const parseChar = x => node => str => {
  const re = new RegExp(`\\${x}([^\\${x}]+)\\${x}`)
  return str.replace(re, (_, m) =>
    `<${node}>${m}</${node}>`
  )
}

 var string = 'This is a *piece* of text.'
 
 var r = parseChar('*')('em')(string)
 
 console.log(r)
```

Comment: actually just one capturing group is needed

Answer (score 4):

You could use replace with a first capturing group where you would capture not a * using a negated character class `([^*]+)` and use the `g` global flag to replace all of them.

`\*([^*]+)\*`

**That would match**

- `\*` Match *
- `([^*]+)` Capture in a group matching not a * one or more times or else you might end up with `<em></em>`
- `\*` Match *

```js
var string = 'This is a *piece* of text and *piece*';
string = string.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, "<em>$1</em>");
console.log(string);
```